# WIF Claims-based Identity for Legacy Login

Tags: asp.net, wif, claims-based-identity, sts-securitytokenservice

I have several legacy ASP.NET applications with custom membership providers.  They also utilized external SAML based identity providers for which we have written custom clients.  I am sold on the value of WIF and ADFS.  The SAML identity providers will work with ADFS but we need to support the legacy membership systems.

Do I need to create a custom STS to handle the legacy authentication?  If so, many developers advice against this for various reasons.  Is there a template or framework which will help me make it secure and scalable?  I have seen SelfSTS and StarterSTS but they both imply they are not for production use.

If not, what are the options?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SelfSTS is a developer tool, meant jsut to streamline the dev process.

StarterSTS is more like a product, only it is not. You have to "own" the code. It essentially means that you need to test it for performance, security, etc.

Vittorio has a good post on it too if you want to do it yourself:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vbertocci/archive/2009/04/23/enhance-your-asp-net-membership-based-website-by-adding-identity-provider-capabilities.aspx

(You will still need to do perf/security testing)